# Why doesn't Videogular font display consistently across browsers?

Tags: css, html, fonts, videogular

In the videogular-themes-default plugin, the videogular font is referenced by videogular.css and lives in the same directory on the server (in .woff, .svg, .eot, and .ttf formats). Different browsers produce different results rendering it. For an easy comparison, look at the "STOP" and "LOGO" buttons of Videogular's example page: http://www.videogular.com/examples/adding-your-custom-buttons/

Chrome and Firefox render it as a serif font; Safari and mobile browsers render it as a sans serif font. Which browsers are doing it correctly? What is going on?

Comment: sounds like a job for http://www.videogular.com/contact/ in addition to asking here - have you done that? (so that if they answer you, rather than an SO reader, you can post the answer yourself)

Comment: I did ask and they haven't responded yet. I'll post the answer if they do respond. (I have to admit, I'm completely stumped by this one. The Chrome and Safari developer bars are both capable of previewing .woff fonts via the Resources/Network tabs, and the same videogular.woff font looks completely different in each preview.)

Comment: Are you sure it's actually the videogular font being used? Which browser(s) show the correct font for you? (My firefox says that the *actual* font used on your example link is Times New Roman, not videogular at all)